# Realm insert and delete object simultaneously in Android

Tags: java, android, realm

I am using Realm 5.0.0 and I want to insert list of object in one table and also want to delete that same object list from another table. I have tried with `Thread` and `AsyncTask` but only one task is getting complete if i delete first and insert later it will only execute insert and if i reverse it it will only execute delete.

```
public static void removeSKUList(final ArrayList<SKUItem> skuItems) {
    final Thread insertThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            try {
                realm.beginTransaction();
                realm.insertOrUpdate(new Memo(String.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID()),
                        false, System.currentTimeMillis(), skuItems));
                realm.commitTransaction();
                } finally {
                realm.close();
                Log.e(TAG, "run: thread2 finished");

            }
        }
    });

    Thread deleteThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            try {
                RealmQuery<SKUItem> query = realm.where(SKUItem.class);
                int i = 0;
                for (SKUItem id : skuItems) {
                    if (i++ > 0) {
                        query = query.or();
                    }
                    query = query.equalTo("sku_number", id.getSku_number());
                }
                realm.beginTransaction();
                RealmResults<SKUItem> skuItems1 = query.findAll();
                skuItems1.deleteAllFromRealm();
                realm.commitTransaction();
                realm.refresh();
            } finally {
                realm.close();
                insertThread.start();
            }
        }
    });
    deleteThread.start();


}
```

Output:

E/RealmManager: run: thread finished

E/RealmManager: run: thread2 finished

But updates only one table last one always....

Update:

```
final Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();                                                                        
try {                                                                                                                  
    final RealmResults<SKUItem> students = realm.where(SKUItem.class).findAll();                                       
    Memo memo = new Memo(String.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID()),                                                            
            false, System.currentTimeMillis(), temStockItems);                                                         
    realm.beginTransaction();                                                                                          
    realm.insertOrUpdate(memo);                                                                                        
    realm.commitTransaction();                                                                                         
    for (SKUItem temStockItem : temStockItems) {                                                                       
        SKUItem skuItem = students.where().equalTo("sku_number", temStockItem.getSku_number()).findFirst();            
        if (skuItem != null) {                                                                                         
            realm.beginTransaction();                                                                                  
            skuItem.deleteFromRealm();                                                                                 
            realm.commitTransaction();                                                                                 
        }                                                                                                              
    }                                                                                                                  
} finally {                                                                                                            
    realm.close();                                                                                                     
}
```

Comment: In my case, there is always problem with using ```realm.commitTransaction()```. How about using ```executeTransaction()``` instead?

Comment: Or, you can use ```executeTransactionAsync()``` in your main Thread(UI thread like ```createView()```) and also, use ```new Realm.OnSuccess()```

Comment: new Realm.OnSuccess() I cant start new executeTransaction() or realm.executeTransactionAsync() also facing same issue...in that

Comment: Realm transaction always works properly on UI Thread. Do you consider this right?

Comment: I am using in seprate  RealmManager

Comment: also tried in UI thread and updated question..but same result

Comment: I don't understand why this is two transactions and I especially don't understand why this is two *threads*

Comment: how i can achieve two transaction at once? @EpicPandaForce

Comment: What do you mean "at once"? Why are they in different transactions? Why are they on different threads? I don't understand what is happening here

Comment: I want delete few object from one table and add them in to another table that's why i am suppose to do two transaction how can i achieve it ? @EpicPandaForce

Comment: I want to delete item from SKUItem table and want to add those in Memo table at once how can i do it? @EpicPandaForce If you know any other approach please suggest me

Answer (score 0):

```
try(Realm r = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
    r.executeTransaction((realm) -> {
        RealmQuery<SKUItem> query = realm.where(SKUItem.class);
        int i = 0;
        for (SKUItem id : skuItems) {
            if (i++ > 0) {
                query = query.or();
            }
            query = query.equalTo("sku_number", id.getSku_number());
        }
        query.findAll().deleteAllFromRealm();
        realm.insertOrUpdate(new Memo(String.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID()),
                false, System.currentTimeMillis(), skuItems));
    });
}
```

Comment: deleteAllFromRealm not deleting object, as I mention only last transaction is executing ...

Comment: Then your query is wrong and you should fix it. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: if i comment the any one part another part is working fine but both are not working that means query is perfect

Comment: Wait, so your problem is that you are inserting the skuItems as part of Memo, and you're expecting it not to get inserted even though you add it as a property? That's kinda weird that you expect objects you insert to not get inserted. They are part of Memo, so they are inserted back as well

Comment: I want to remove that SKUItems which are inserted in memo that's all I want to do

Comment: Then just don't re-insert them, give `Collections.emptyList()` to the memo!